# 'Sequential' object has no attribute '_in_multi_worker_mode'

Tags: python, tensorflow, sequential

I tried to use google colab resources to save my CNN model weights and I get this error. I tried googling it but nothing helps.

> 'Sequential' object has no attribute '_in_multi_worker_mode'

My code:

```
checkpoint_path = "training_1/cp.ckpt"
checkpoint_dir = os.path.dirname(checkpoint_path)
cp_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(checkpoint_path, save_weights_only=True, verbose=1)


cnn_model = Sequential()
cnn_model.add(Conv2D(filters = 64, kernel_size = (3,3), activation = "relu", input_shape = Input_shape ))
cnn_model.add(Conv2D(filters = 64, kernel_size = (3,3), activation = "relu"))
cnn_model.add(MaxPooling2D(2,2))
cnn_model.add(Dropout(0.4))

cnn_model = Sequential()
cnn_model.add(Conv2D(filters = 128, kernel_size = (3,3), activation = "relu"))
cnn_model.add(Conv2D(filters = 128, kernel_size = (3,3), activation = "relu"))
cnn_model.add(MaxPooling2D(2,2))
cnn_model.add(Dropout(0.3))


cnn_model.add(Flatten())

cnn_model.add(Dense(units = 512, activation = "relu"))
cnn_model.add(Dense(units = 512, activation = "relu"))

cnn_model.add(Dense(units = 10, activation = "softmax"))

history = cnn_model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size = 32,epochs = 1, 
shuffle = True, callbacks = [cp_callback])
```

Stack trace:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-35c1db9636b7> in <module>()
----> 1 history = cnn_model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size = 32,epochs = 1, shuffle = True, callbacks = [cp_callback])

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/callbacks.py in on_train_begin(self, logs)
    903   def on_train_begin(self, logs=None):
    904     # pylint: disable=protected-access
--> 905     if self.model._in_multi_worker_mode():
    906       # MultiWorkerTrainingState is used to manage the training state needed
    907       # for preemption-recovery of a worker in multi-worker training.

AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute '_in_multi_worker_mode'
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  Please see how to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 17):

I've recently faced the same issue

instead of,

```
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
```

use,

```
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
```

Answer (score 3):

Check your tensorflow version. You actually only need to synchronize it. check if all your import uses

```
from keras import ...
```

or

```
from tensorflow.keras import ...
```

use only one of the above for your keras imports. using different (both) at the same time can cause collision by the libraries.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint
```

in your model building process, you can use

```
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
```

in order to import `ModelCheckpoint`, and then just use `ModelCheckpoint` in the later code.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if your version of tensorflow matches the latest one.In my case the error was solved when is updated it to 2.1.0.